# Is the following statement of differentiability theorem correct?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

My book gives the following differentiability theorem:

> If the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist near $(a,b)$ and are continuous at $(a,b)$, then $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$.

If the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ are continuous near $(a,b)$, they exist near $(a,b)$. So can we also state the differentiability theorem as:

> If the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ are continuous near $(a,b)$, then $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$.

Comment: My book says that, too.  Does your give a proof?

Comment: Nothing like that written in my book. It was just my reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. You will find a proof of the first statement in many textbboks, such as, for instance, *Elementary Classical Analysis*, by Jerrold Marsden and Michael J. Hoffman. Actually, the standard proof (which  uses the Mean Value Theorem) is not hard.

Note that the second statement (which is easily deduced from the first one) assumes continuity at all points near $(a,b)$ and deduces from it that the function is differentiable in that area.

Comment: If the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ are continuous near $(a,b)$, they exist near (a,b). Is this statement also correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Can you refer me a book or online article for the proof of this statement?

Comment: Can it be found in "Elementary Classical Analysis, by Jerrold Marsden and Michael J. Hoffman"?

Comment: No, I cannot. It's too basic. It is **obvious** that if a function is continuous at a point then, in particular, it is defined there.